# Stock Huawei Honor7 Notification Question

Tags: notifications, huawei, background-process

Im developing a small app which shows notifications continuously, also when the app is stopped via swipe in the task manager or when the device reboots.
It works fine on old Samsung Galaxy Tab2 7 (Android 4.2) and Nexus5 Emulator (stock Android 5.1) among other Android 4.x.x emulators.

Unfortunately it doesn't work on my Huawei Honor7 with Android 5.1 and EMUI 3.1 overlay. Process stops as soon as the app is closed via swipe. Also autostart after boot up doesnt work. I'm not sure if its a Huawei-Power-Safe-Something (killing background processes) or if Android 5.1 generally introduced a new notifications-policy. At least the 5.1-emulator shows, that its still works.

If its a Huawei-thing, maybe someone may tell he, how to tweak the settings for apps right? I already installes PM Plus and granted all possible access to my app but no success yet =\

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found the solution - problem was (probably) within the MIUI-Overlay:
I had to install PM Plus-App for Huawei/Honor to unlock the "Startmanager"-menue within the preinstalled "Telefonmanager-App" (german version - english may be "security app"??)
Inside the "startmanager"-menue one can toggle on/off autostart for installed apps. After switching the mode, the phone has to reboot to take effect. BUT in my case the desired app HAD TO BE RUNNING when turning of the phone for the reboot.
Its now working fine and i receive notifications even with closed app and after a reboot.